# Try-with-resources using conditional expression

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA 14 gives me the warning "PrintStream used without try-with-resources" when it sees this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (PrintStream out = args.length > 0 ? new PrintStream(args[0]) : null) {
        if (out != null)
            out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

Using `javap -c` I can see that the resource is closed as expected at the end of the try block.

The warning is issued only when creating the resource in a conditional expression, as above; it's not issued when done in the typical way.

Is this an IDEA bug or does it have a valid point?

Comment: Presumably there's some code inside the block (not using the `PrintStream`) that explains why the try-with-resources isn't *inside* the `if` block?

Comment: Using eclipse, this con't doesn't give me any warning... it works just fine!

Comment: Just another reason to never to use tri-nary operators ;) (I tease, but I'm not entirely joking, I've found that almost every case where one is used, refactoring can make things easier to read.(especially for new devs)) Might  want to just make simple helper method if if you want to save code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think IDEA is just confused by it. That looks like a valid `try-with-resources` to me. [JLS§14.20.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3) shows the *Resource* part of the statement as being:

> Resource:
>   
>   *{VariableModifier}* *UnannType* *VariableDeclaratorId* = *Expression*

...and doesn't seem to place restrictions on the *Expression*. So I don't see why an expression potentially yielding `null` would make it somehow invalid, and the translated "simple" example from [§14.20.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.1):

```
{
    final {VariableModifierNoFinal} R Identifier = Expression;
    Throwable #primaryExc = null;

    try ResourceSpecification_tail
        Block
    catch (Throwable #t) {
        #primaryExc = #t;
        throw #t;
    } finally {
        if (Identifier != null) {
            if (#primaryExc != null) {
                try {
                    Identifier.close();
                } catch (Throwable #suppressedExc) {
                    #primaryExc.addSuppressed(#suppressedExc);
                }
            } else {
                Identifier.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...would be just fine with it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is in principle no problem so the warning that IntelliJ gives can be ignored.

However, your code would be much clearer if you wrote it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    if (args.length > 0) {
        try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(args[0])) {
            out.println("Hello, world!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and I agree with this particular piece of code; however, my real code is much more complex than the cut-down-to-bare-minimum version I used for this question.