# Fortify - Unreleased Resource Streams issue for having a ternary in try-with-resources

Tags: java, fortify

I have recently scanned our code base with Fortify and I'm confused as to why it's flagging certain issues. One issue that I'm facing the issue is with releasing a resource.

Here is a snippet for context.

```
 String someLocation = getPathToTheLocation(); //gives location
 try (InputStream in = someLocation == null ? Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("someFile.xml") : new FileInputStream(new File(someLocation))) {

/// Do Something

}
```

Fortify complains that the method that has this try-with-resources block fails to release a system resource allocated by FileInputStream(). Doesn't the try-with-resources help me close the FileInputStream automatically?

Just assuming that Fortify doesn't recognize the try-with-resources paradigm, I refrained from using it and did it the regular way.

```
String someLocation = getPathToTheLocation(); //gives location
InputStream in = null;
try {
  in = someLocation == null ? Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("someFile.xml") 
            : new FileInputStream(new File(someLocation));

//Do Something.

} finally {
    assert in != null;
    try {
      in.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Could not close input stream.", ioe);
    }
}
```

And yet it still complains about the resource being unreleased. What could be the actual issue here that I fail to recognize?

Comment: Fortify is pretty comprehensive, but it is far from perfect.  I’m guessing the ternary operator is confusing it.  Perhaps a private method, like `private InputStream open(String location)`, would be less likely to confuse Fortify.

Answer (score 1):

I think everything okay with the code, the problem in Fortify and maybe you should propose an Issue for it. There was quite the same issue with Idea - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34655863/5790043.